# How can I get the value of a span element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have tested every solution I have found on Internet, but none of them works.

I have this HTML:

```
<h4>Códigos disponibles:<span id="codesQuantity">@Model.ExternalCodesForThisProduct</span></h4>
```

And this Javascript:

```
$('#eCodesFrm').on('submit', function (e) { //use on if jQuery 1.7+
    e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
    var availableCodes = $("#codesQuantity");

    var totalCodesUsed = 0;
    alert(availableCodes);
    $('#eCodesFrm *').filter(':input').each(function () {
        if (this.name.match(/.Quantity$/)) {
            totalCodesUsed = totalCodesUsed + parseInt(this.value, 10);
        }
    });
```

But `availableCodes` is `[object Object]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `var availableCodes = jQuery("#codesQuantity");`

Comment: Are to trying to get the inner text?

Comment: if `$` is referring to jQuery object... even if the element is not available `undefined` won't be returned.. an empty jQuery object will be retunred

Comment: so since you are getting `undefined`... it looks like `$` is no longer referring to jQuery

Comment: @VansFannel Hey you initially told us like, you are receiving `undefined`??? But now you changed it.. Follow shaunak's suggestion

Comment: Best way to `help your self` is to use `console.log(availableCodes)` instead of `alert(availableCodes)` ,  it says almost everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're assigning a jQuery object to your variable, and not the content of the element. To extract the text inside the `<span>`, you should use either [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/), and do this instead:

```
var availableCodes = $("#codesQuantity").text();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the inner element try [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/). As long as it's plain text in there there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

To get the text inside the `<span>` use [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
jQuery("#codesQuantity").text()   //or $("#codesQuantity").text() if $ is jQuery in your code.
```